# How to get nrow=ncol for DESeq2?

Tags: row, sequence, col

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPOr1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oqf1.png)

Hello,
I am unsure how to get nrow=ncol to create the data matrix for DESeq2. The number of variables are the same, but the first column of my countData is counted, bringing the total to 22 columns when I have 21 variables, so it is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.